Getting issue to show update prompt In-App-Update
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    checkForUpdate();
  }

  checkForUpdate() async {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    print("pack name : ${packageInfo.buildNumber}");
    print("checking for update");
    try {
      InAppUpdate.checkForUpdate().then((info) async {
        if (info.updateAvailability == UpdateAvailability.updateAvailable) {
          print("update Available");
          update();
        }
      }).catchError((e) {
        print(e.toString());
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  update() async {
    print("updating");
    var update = await InAppUpdate.startFlexibleUpdate();
    if (update == AppUpdateResult.success) {
      showUpdatePrompt(
        context,
        cancel: () {
          print("cancel Update");
        },
        onTap: () async {
          print("Completing Update");
          InAppUpdate.completeFlexibleUpdate()
              .then((value) => {})
              .catchError((e) {
            print(e.toString());
            return {};
          });
        },
      );
    }
  }

  showUpdatePrompt(
    BuildContext context, {
    required Function onTap,
    required Function cancel,
  }) async {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: Text(
            'Update Prompt',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListBody(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Update the App new version',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                // Text('You can add more content here.'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              child: Text('OK',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              onPressed: () {
                onTap();
                cancel;
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Cancel', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close the dialog
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

In my app when a user opens the apk for the first time it checke for in app updated if there is available the apk starts to download it .. when the downloading is completed the user is shown an prompt of completed and asked for installation if user allow installation the new updated version gets installed
Now the problem occurs that when user denies the installation and opens the apk again then the prompt of update is not coming ...
I have searched and looked for solution everywhere but iam not able to find anything
To show the in app update prompt again when the user come on the same screen
